# Is a more generic solution possible?

Tags: c#, generics, audit.net

I think what I want to do is not possible. 
However, I would like to make sure that it is indeed not possible.

I use Audit.Net as a framework to add auditing to a system that has already been completed.
There are many different objects that may be sent for auditing. I have to get hold of the properties of those objects and send them to the database. In some cases, I would want the old values and the new values, and therefore I use the Target property of AuditEvent, otherwise if I just need the new values I use the CustomField property.

Is there any way to make the following more generic, so that I don't have to repeat these lines for each type of object like `SimpleResult`, `LeaveRequest`, `Incident` etc?
There is unfortunately no commonality between the objects being audited.

```
SimpleResult objOld = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleResult>(auditEvent.Target.SerializedOld.ToString());                      

SimpleResult objNew = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SimpleResult>(auditEvent.Target.SerializedNew.ToString());                       

if (auditEvent.Target.Type.ToString() == "SimpleResult")
{
       InsertTargetObjectFields<SimpleResult>(objOld, objNew, auditControlTableID, auditEvent);                           
}
```

Here is where I get hold of the properties and send them off to the database:

```
 public void InsertTargetObjectFields<T>(T objOld, T objNew, int? auditControlTableID, AuditEvent auditEvent)
    {
        using (ESSDataContext ess_context = new ESSDataContext())
        {
            try
            {   
                foreach (var property in objOld.GetType().GetProperties().Where(property => !property.GetGetMethod().GetParameters().Any()))
                {
                   //Check for null values and get hold of oldValue and newValue

                        var sqlResult = ess_context.InsertAuditTable(resourceTag, dbObjectName, username, property.Name, oldValue,
                            newValue, auditEvent.StartDate, auditControlTableID.ToString(),
                            auditEvent.Environment.CallingMethodName);

                }
            }

        }
    }
```

I've tried using `dynamic`, but then I don't get the properties correctly.

Comment: If you have access to `SimpleRequest`, `LeaveRequest`, `Incident`, etc you could make them extend a class w/o any functionality and use that class as your generic type in methods. Might not be a good manner way of handling your problem but it works as far as I have used it with Streams.
Oh and you can replace `.Any()` with `.ToList().ForEach(property => { ... })`

Comment: Where are you calling `InsertTargetObjectFields`? is that a custom action or a custom data provider?

Comment: @thepirat000, the first batch of code is in the overriden `InsertEvent` of my custom `AuditDataProvider`. `InsertTargetObjectFields` is a separate method in the same custom class that extends `AuditDataProvider`.

Comment: @JieBäf, guess I could make them all extend a class... but it feels a bit synthetic. Thanks for your comment though. I'll think about implementing it...